# Pywin32 is not found when I create a file

Tags: python, pywin32

When I execute it manually through `Python IDLE 3.4 32Bit` the import and everything works just as expected. But when I try and create a file and then write the import and every other code, for some ODD reason it cannot find the filepath. Is it because I'm putting the file in my desktop?

```
import win32com.client as comclt

wsh = comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
wsh.SendKeys("Hello")
```

***Extra Information***

Python Version: 3.4
Pywin32 Version: pywin32-219.win32-py3.4

System Type: 32 Bit

ERROR Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RepeaterCreeper/Desktop/tested.py", line 1, in <module>
import win32com.client as comclt
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

*If you need more information do let me know down in the comments below and I will be sure to add it as soon as I see your comment.*

Comment: How do you run the .py file? Can you provide a welcome output of command `python`?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov When I run the `python` command it returns an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    python
NameError: name 'python' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely an issue with python not being in your environment.

Check your PATH

```
Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced.
Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
Add python directory to path ,end it with ;
```

Comment: It works! Great thank you very much. I will give your bounty when it's available.